# some minor bugs related to Spring boot build grandle - QueryDSL that I haven't been able to solve for the past two days

Tags: java, spring-boot, build.gradle

Hi everyone i am having some Spring boot related problem for last 2 days but i have not found a solution to it i tried to use QueryDSL it spawned Q classes respectively, then I try to run my project again but it says missing Classes in my model or entity, if anyone has the same problem and solved it please help me, I'm a newbie so many unknown questions, hopefully I will get the best answer from some master soon.

and here is what i tried.

This is when i deleted the QueryDSL related stuff and everything worked fine.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q29OI.png)

and this is after I used QueryDSL, it still generated the QClass exactly as I wanted, and I ran my project again and it said missing files in the model even though I had it.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ZdvL.png)

Everyone if anyone has the answer, or need to see anything from my source code just let me know, I am always willing to provide the code related to this for the best help, again I'm a newbie, so please don't be harsh with me.

A big thank you to everyone who came across here and read this post from me. Thank you very much.

I've been searching how to fix it for 2 days specifically 27 hours without sleep, but haven't found a way to fix it.

help me

Comment: Please remove unnecessary speech like "please I\ve been searching for days" or "hopefully I'll get the answer from a master"